# reply via email link under each post

Tags: email

I came across this post https://destroytoday.com/blog/reply-link-in-rss-feed-posts where author added reply via email link under each post. I understand this is done by modifying the loop.

After further research on the topic I came across this article https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-link-to-an-email-address-in-wordpress/ where they recommend against this option as it might cause a barrage of spam.

**Question:** it seems very convenient option if comments are off, however, can this really cause lots of spam email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it can. There's lots of bots out there looking specifically for `mailto` links. That's why a lot of people obfuscate those links and with some cooked up or framework javascript put it back together on click. But a very clever bot could simulate that even.

It's a cost and benefits question. Do you really want people to be able to email you with as less steps as possible? Then accept the possibility of spam and invest in a good spam filter / provider.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I will probably skip that option as I think if people really want to get in touch with a question, they can just use contact form on my site.